# Split pandas dataframe based on proximity of the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bigdata

I have a big indexed dataframe which I would like to group based on their indexes. The data is indexed like this:

```
Index 
...    
79228         
79230         
79232         
101930      
101932      
101934
101936
101938      
147224      
147226      
147228
147230
...
```

How it should be grouped:

```
Index     group_id
...
79228     1  
79230     1    
79232     1    
101930    2  
101932    2  
101934    2
101936    2
101938    2  
147224    3  
147226    3  
147228    3
147230    3
...
```

One option is to iterate over each row using DataFrame.iterrows() and compare the indexes but that seems very inefficient. Is there a pandas way that can do it more efficiently?

Note: The amount and value of indexes in the same range is random, so I can't group that way.

The data is separated by a large number. For example one index is 80 000 and the following is 100 000.

Comment: How are you differentiating between indexes? Do you have the number of times one group id should be repeated?

Comment: I'm differentiating between the indexes based on their distance to each other. For example: if (bigger_index - smaller_index < threshold) it belongs to the same group.

The number of times one group id is repeated is arbitrary and can vary greatly.

Comment: After reading all the comments I think your questions is really more about grouping and less about pandas. @jpp's answer takes care of all the pandas, and can mostly be adapted for any simple method you'd like to group by. If it can't be done with a simple method then you might need to employ the [big guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to set your tolerance level. Here we calculate floored quotient by 100 and factorize.

```
df['NewIndex'] = (df['Index'].diff() > 100).cumsum() + 1

#    Index  NewIndex
# 0      1         1
# 1      3         1
# 2      8         1
# 3   1003         2
# 4   1005         2
# 5   1006         2
# 6   3005         3
# 7   3010         3
# 8   3016         3
```

**Explanation**

- Find rows where difference is above a threshold, e.g. 100.
- Use `pd.Series.cumsum()` to roll these markers into groups.
- Add 1 for desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think a quotient based approach would work, because the index value is completely arbitrary. I updated the data in my question to better reflect this.

Comment: @M9M5M, I tested with your new data.. it still works. I suggest you update again!

Comment: This works if the data is separated by predictable data thresholds (e.g. 100) but for an array = {199, 200, 201, 333, 334, 335} the 199 would be in a different group than 200 and 201, or am I missing something?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the added explanation.